# Data isn't retrieved from database (SQLCODE 100) even though data exists

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, cobol

I'm fetching data from my database where one of the conditions will always be the same, and the other one will have a value from 1 to 13. The query has to be executed 13 times, once for each value.

Everything compiles, but when I look at the output I notice that the values used to retrieve data from the `SELECT` statement never hold any value. When I execute the exact same query with hardcoded `WHERE` statements in SQL Server Management Studio, data is retrieved as expected. 
The `SQLCODE` I receive is `100`.

When I omit the `PERFORM VARYING` loop and give my query hardcoded data, my `QUESTION-CODE` and `ANSWER-CODE` fields contain the correct data, but the `AMOUNT` one is first empty, then zero.

I'm using the OpenCobol compiler with SQL Server 2012.

What am I overlooking?

```
01 WS-FIELDS.
    05 I PIC 9(2).

01 WS-EVALUATION.
    05 QUESTION-CODE PIC 9(3).
    05 ANSWER-CODE PIC 9(3).

01 WS-RESULT.
    05 OV PIC 9(3).
    05 V PIC 9(3).
    05 G PIC 9(3).
    05 ZG PIC 9(3).
    05 NVT PIC 9(3).
    05 AMOUNT PIC 9(3).

LINKAGE SECTION.
    01 ROUTE-CODE PIC X(10) VALUE SPACES.

   EXEC SQL
    DECLARE crs 
     CURSOR FOR
      SELECT QuestionCode, AnswerCode, COUNT(AnswerCode)
      FROM Answers
      WHERE Route = :ROUTE-CODE AND QuestionCode= :I
      GROUP BY QuestionCode, AnswerCode
    END-EXEC

    EXEC SQL
     OPEN crs
    END-EXEC

    PERFORM UNTIL SQLCODE <> 0
     PERFORM VARYING I FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL I = 13

      EXEC SQL
       FETCH crs INTO :QUESTION-CODE, :ANSWER-CODE, AMOUNT
      END-EXEC

      IF SQLCODE = 0
       EVALUATE TRUE 
        WHEN ANSWER-CODE = 1
         MOVE AMOUNT TO OV
        WHEN ANSWER-CODE = 2
         MOVE AMOUNT TO V
        WHEN ANSWER-CODE = 3
         MOVE AMOUNT TO G
        WHEN ANSWER-CODE = 4
         MOVE AMOUNT TO ZG
        WHEN ANSWER-CODE = 5
         MOVE AMOUNT TO NVT
        WHEN OTHER
         DISPLAY "Error" UPON SYSOUT
       END-EVALUATE
      END-IF

     END-PERFORM
    END-PERFORM
   .
```

Comment: I do not know about SQL Server, but for DB2 100 is row not found. It could be caused a mismatch in the type. Try changing Route = trim(:Route), also is question code numeric ??? try defining I as comp sync.

Comment: I've added LTRIM(RTRIM()) and changed the field definition to comp sync: neither made a difference. I believe the error exists because of the cursor declaration: it's declared with variable `I`, but this value is never overwritten. How should I fix this? Can I overwrite this cursor every time with a new value of I?

Comment: No, change the SQL to QuestionCode between 1 and 13 (or is it 0 and 14, I would need to check) and do not use PERFORM VARYING I FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL I = 13, you just need the PERFORM UNTIL SQLCODE <> 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change as Follows:

```
    EXEC SQL
     DECLARE crs 
      CURSOR FOR
        SELECT QuestionCode, AnswerCode, COUNT(AnswerCode)
        FROM Answers
        WHERE Route = :ROUTE-CODE AND QuestionCode between 1 and 13
        GROUP BY QuestionCode, AnswerCode
        Order By QuestionCode
    END-EXEC

    EXEC SQL
     OPEN crs
    END-EXEC

    EXEC SQL
     FETCH crs
       ......
    END-EXEC

    PERFORM UNTIL SQLCODE <> 0

      EXEC SQL
        FETCH crs
          ......
      END-EXEC
    End-Perform
```

**Note:** You may need to check if a QuestionCode is missing depending on data / logic

Also in Cobol PERFORM UNTIL SQLCODE <> 0 is actually a while loop in most languages.
If you want the test done at the end of the Loop, use the **With Test After** option.

Alternative you could remove the cursor and a select in the loop for each row.

Comment: That solved the problem (at least: I'm 99% sure it did. Can't tell entirely for sure because the value of `COUNT(AnswerCode)` isn't being inputted in the variable)! Small note though: the `ORDER BY` clause has to be placed after the `GROUP BY`.